# Is the 'for loop' for x used in this code a valid substitute for while x<=num?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve this problem of displaying prime numbers upto a specified number.

While I have the standard solution for it. I first tried to solve it myself and ended up writing this code. But I'm not getting the desired output. The standard solution uses the while loop as the main loop. And if that's the ideal loop for this example, why would that be so ?

```py
def count_primes(num):
    my_primes=[2]
    if num<2:
        return 0
    for x in range(3,num+1,2):
            for y in range(3,x+1):
                if x%y==0:
                    break
            else:
                my_primes.append(x)
    return my_primes

count_primes(100)
```

I expected a list of all prime numbers up to 100. Instead the output displayed only [2]. My guess is that the 'break' keyword broke out of the entire loop instead of only the if loop.

Comment: Hint: Try printing the found factor for each x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second for loop change `range(3,x+1)` to `range(3,x)`, since your loop goes until `y=x` and `x%x` is always 0.